# Security script: make value lowercase and remove spaces before applying

Tags: php, security, registration, spam-prevention

On my registration page, I have a security question that the user has to answer. It works great and have stopped spam bots.

Here is the script (very lightweight):

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'add_register_field' );
function add_register_field() { ?>
    <p>
        <label><?php _e('What is the name of the ship in the TV show Firefly?') ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="user_proof" id="user_proof" class="input" size="25" tabindex="20" /></label>
    </p>
<?php }

add_action( 'register_post', 'add_register_field_validate', 10, 3 );
function add_register_field_validate( $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors) {
    if (!isset($_POST[ 'user_proof' ]) || empty($_POST[ 'user_proof' ])) {
        return $errors->add( 'proofempty', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question.'  );
    } elseif ( strtolower( $_POST[ 'user_proof' ] ) != 'serenity' ) {
        return $errors->add( 'prooffail', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question correctly.'  );
    }
}
```

And here is a picture of how it looks:

[image]

So the answer the user has to input is `serenity`. The problem is that some users type it as `Serenity`, or add a random blank space somewhere.

My question is, how can I make it so that the value they input gets converted to lowercase and any blank spaces are removed *prior* to checking if the value is correct? This way, if they input `Ser enItY`, it will be fine.

Comment: strtolower() will make string to lowercase. str_replace() or some regular expression will help you remove the spaces in string. trim() will also help you remove spaces left and right of string. Since you tagged php this question, i assume you want the server-side functions, and not any js code to do the same thing.

Comment: @andrew No definitely server-side. Can you please write up an answer with your suggestions? If you do, please use my code as referrence.

Comment: It will stop a few users as well.... I didn't know the answer to that question, until I googled it a moment ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str_replace(' ', '', $string)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove white-spaces; [`trim($string)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove any other "junk" around input; [`strtolower($string)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to get string in lowercase. To compare string use [`strcmp($string, $string1)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) In the end you get:

```
if (strcmp('serenity', strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', trim($_POST['user_proof'])))) == 0)
```

In your code:

```
function add_register_field_validate($sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors) {
    if (empty($_POST['user_proof'])) {
        return $errors->add('proofempty', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question.' );
    } elseif (strcmp('serenity', strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', trim($_POST['user_proof'])))) != 0) {
        return $errors->add('prooffail', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question correctly.' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please update your question and show me exactly where I add this in the add_register_field_validate function?

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_proof = $_POST[ 'user_proof' ]; // this is the form field being posted.
$user_proof = strtolower($user_proof); // this will convert it to lower case
$user_proof = str_replace(" ", "", $user_proof); // this will remove spaces in string
```

**EIDT:** As per your request:

```
function add_register_field_validate( $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors) 
{
   if (!isset($_POST[ 'user_proof' ]) || empty($_POST[ 'user_proof' ])) 
   {
    return $errors->add( 'proofempty', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question.'  );
   } 

   $user_proof = $_POST[ 'user_proof' ]; // this is the form field being posted.
   $user_proof = strtolower($user_proof); // this will convert it to lower case
   $user_proof = str_replace(" ", "", $user_proof); // this will remove spaces in string

   if ( $user_proof != 'serenity' ) 
   {
    return $errors->add( 'prooffail', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question correctly.'  );
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question and show me exactly where I add this in the add_register_field_validate function?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($input != 'serenity'){
    //Show errors
}

function add_register_field_validate( $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors) {


    if (!isset($_POST[ 'user_proof' ]) || empty($_POST[ 'user_proof' ])) {
        return $errors->add( 'proofempty', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question.'  );
    } elseif (strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['user_proof'])))) != 'serenity' ) {
        return $errors->add( 'prooffail', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question correctly.'  );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question and show me exactly where I add this in the add_register_field_validate function?